# Java Reflection call to method with Generic parameters

Tags: java, reflection

How to call a method through a Reflection, when it has a generic parameter, like  bellow snippet -

```
@Test
    public void testOptional() throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException,
            IllegalAccessException
    {
        AtomicReference<ClassA> atomicReference = new AtomicReference<>(new ClassA());
        ClassB classB = new ClassB();

        Method method = MyTest.class.getDeclaredMethod("doSomething", AtomicReference.class, ClassB.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(atomicReference, classB);
    }

    private void doSomething(AtomicReference<ClassA> classA, ClassB classB){

        System.out.println("Hi do not poke me, I am working!");
    }
```

It gives me -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doSomething` method is part of `MyTest` class. `Method::invoke` will have to take three parameters :

- instance of `MyTest` class on which the method will be invoked.
- instance of `AtomicReference`
- instance of `ClassB`

So it should look like this :

```
public void testOptional() throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException,
            IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        AtomicReference<ClassA> atomicReference = new AtomicReference<>(new ClassA());
        ClassB classB = new ClassB();

        MyTest myTest = new MyTest(); // here we create the object

        Method method = MyTest.class.getDeclaredMethod("doSomething", AtomicReference.class, ClassB.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(myTest, atomicReference, classB); //we invoke doSomething on myTest object with parameters
}
```

Also keep in mind that generics are erased at compile time. So every generic type is `Object` at runtime.